# Understanding ActionLink and it overloaded constructors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

#### Edit-Info:

Question narrowed to make it simpler to answer. 
If you are already about to answer the first version i can roll back this edit or post an additional question.

#### Intro

I am starting to learn [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) and wanted to create an anchor link that has an click event associated to load information from a controller using an ajax-call.

According to [an article on c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/) action link has several overloads like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", // <-- Link text
  "Index" // <-- Action Method Name
)
// rendered html: <a href="/">Click here</a>


@Html.ActionLink("Click here", // <-- Link text
  "About", // <-- Action Method Name
  "Home", // <-- Controller Name
  null, // <-- Route value
  null // <-- htmlArguments
)
// rendered html: <a href="/Home/About">Click here</a>
```

#### Problem and my efforts

But it seems that these overloads of [Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Controls.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.mvc.controls.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)  are not documented. I have looked at the [mvc-source-code of the class ActionLink](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/Controls/ActionLink.cs) but i found only the implicit default constructor.

#### Question

Can you help me to understand how the apparently undocumented overloads work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is most definitely documented on MSDN.

Also, these are not constructors. HTML helpers such as ActionLink are implemented as static [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Could you elaborate how the [extension method `ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) from the class `System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions` and the [ActionLink class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.mvc.controls.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) relate to the razor syntax `@Html.ActionLink(...)`?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but since the ActionLink class inherits System.Web.UI.Control I would presume that it is a control that is designed to work with ASP.NET .aspx pages rather than with MVC.